# NestJs Dependency injection get multiple instance in a single class

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a class Item below

```
@Injectable()
export class Item {
   name: string;
}
```

I am injecting Item class into ItemService

```
export class ItemService {
    constructor(private readonly item: Item) {}
    
    save(items) {
        items.forEach((data) => {
            this.item.name = data.name;
            this.item.save();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is I am not getting new instance of item for every loop. How can I achieve this with dependency injection in nestjs.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting new instance of item for every loop.
> Blockquote

That's what dependency injection is, you inject the already created object of class if available, It follows the singleton pattern.

> How can I achieve this with dependency injection in nestjs.

By creating a new object in each iteration;

```
import item from 'Item'

export class ItemService {
    constructor() {}
    
    save(items) {
        items.forEach((data) => { 
            item = new Item()
            item.name = data.name;
            item.save();
        });
    }
}
```